# Crockpot soup issue

Tags: food-safety, soup, crockpot

I fried hamburger up and planned on making hamburger macaroni soup in my crockpot. I put the cooked hamburger in the crockpot, added uncooked noodles and the tomato sauce. Turned crockpot on low overnight. Somehow the crockpot got unplugged and my noodles didn't fully cook, and everything was completely cold by morning. Is it safe to plug in and continue cooking? My guess is the crockpot was unplugged for 8+ hours.